# OSMnx- why is the 'walk' network larger than 'all' network?

Tags: openstreetmap, infrastructure, osmnx

I export and compare the km length of the total network and then the pedestrian network via OSMnx. The strange thing is that for some cities the walk network is larger than the total network. How can this be explained? I checked the queries in the custom filter of the OSMnx code and I still can't explain it, since network='walk' is a stricter definition, thus should be contained in the all network...

Try out this code and let me know if you have any explanations.

```
place = 'Empire state building, New York, NY 10001, USA'

# import graph all
G_a = ox.graph_from_address(place, retain_all=True, network_type='all', simplify=True, clean_periphery=False)

# import graph walk 
G_w = ox.graph_from_address(place, retain_all=True, network_type='walk', simplify=True, clean_periphery=False) 


print('all: ', G_a.size(weight='length'), 'walk: ', G_w.size(weight='length'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `walk` network type is fully bidirectional, meaning that each pair of adjacent nodes has at least two edges between them (there could be more than two if the nodes are directly linked by multiple street segments, as this is a MultiDiGraph), one pointing from node `u` to `v` and the other pointing from node `v` to `u`. Pedestrians can walk either direction on any street, so all edges must be bidirectional in a walking network.

The `all` network type is not fully bidirectional as it makes no presumptions about who or what may flow through it. Hence, all of its edges obey one-way directionality constraints when present, meaning that some of its nodes may only be linked by a single one-way edge.

This is why you may see more edges in a `walk` network's model than in an `all` network's model. However, your `all` network will always have at least as many nodes as your `walk` network, as you can see here:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

place = 'Empire state building, New York, NY 10001, USA'
G_a = ox.graph_from_address(place, retain_all=True, network_type='all', 
                            simplify=True, clean_periphery=False)
G_w = ox.graph_from_address(place, retain_all=True, network_type='walk', 
                            simplify=True, clean_periphery=False)
assert len(G_a) >= len(G_w)
```

You can also see and set which `network_type` arguments are treating as bidirectional with the `bidirectional_network_types` setting:

```py
print(ox.settings.bidirectional_network_types)
```

The `bidirectional_network_types` setting will be exposed via `ox.config()` in the next release of OSMnx.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. So the `all`  network does not consider `walk` edged as bidirectional by default. Whereas the ‘walk’ network does. Thus, the `all` network length will be greater or equal than `walk` (as I expected) only if users in OSM have explicitly tagged 2 edges (1 per direction) for the same node pair, for each pedestrian street. 

So perhaps one way of comparing infrastructure length is by using `.street_length_total` which counts only considering one direction…?

Comment: No, OSMnx treats each OSM way in an `all` network as bidirectional and gives it two reciprocal edges, unless it is tagged one-way on OSM. In a `walk` network, OSMnx just ignores any one-way tagging and treats everything as bidirectional. You could use its `get_undirected` function if you want an undirected representation of the graph with just one edge per OSM way, then count lengths.